# Change display name of subview in cordova windows platform

Tags: javascript, windows, angular, cordova

I'm developing an hybrid app using cordova and angular 2. In my app, I use window.open() to open a new subview. Could I use javascript, cordova plugin, angular plugin or something else to change the name of the new subview window? (using code, not using CLI or config.xml)